# Android Studio debugger is not connecting

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

I can't attach debugger with my device, i've tried all the previous solutions that i found but still error remains same.

I'm using **android studio version 1.4.1.
OS: Mac os x 10.10**

**Tested on Devices: Nexus4, Nexus5**

**Unable to open debugger port : java.net.ConnectException “Connection refused”**

Will anyone please answer this question?

Comment: Connect your phone to Mac via usb. Goto ``Setting -> Developper options -> USB debugging -> check``. Then check have your phone name in here ``Apple Menu -> About this Mac -> System report ->USB`` ???

Comment: My device is visible in the android monitor. USB debugging is already checked.

Comment: are you try ``fuser -k 8601/tcp`` . Refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28283610/1520438

Comment: @DanhDC I've already tried this. I tried once again and the results are:
 command: lsof -i tcp:8601
results: studio  802 shahbazsaleem  275u  IPv4 0x4d81fdb13fe1005      0t0  TCP 192.168.2.102:52359->localhost:8601 (SYN_SENT)